# Is there a Database of votes data in world's parliaments

Tags: parliament, voting-records

Following [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/82705/comparative-study-of-party-discipline-in-democratic-countries) I was thinking if there is any "DB" official or not containing information about parliaments votes containing the subject of the vote and its results by every member. After all, this data is already open -- it is just not in a very accessible form for data analysis. Ideally, I would like to have one big DB containing many parliaments, but even DB (or for that matter any computer-readable document(s)) for specific houses are good. Are there any? So many interesting questions can be answered using those.

**Edit:**

In the UK parliament, there is a [repository for votes](https://votes.parliament.uk/). Each vote has its own page ([most recent example](https://votes.parliament.uk/votes/commons/division/1671): "Digital Markets, Competition and Consumers Bill: New Clause 30"). Importantly the user can download the results also in a csv format that contains 5 columns: "Member", "Party", "Constituency", "Vote", "Proxy Member".

This kind of data and breakdown is exactly what I'm looking for. I would like all the votes to be in one big file (which can be done relatively easily if it is legal). If other parliaments also present information like this UK one, I would like to know (language barriers makes it harder to find) - or else it already occurred to somebody in 2023 that this kind of data should be available and they compiled the data by themselves (i.e., this is not "official" data).

Comment: As a caveat to any such database: A lot of parliaments have some sort of [voice vote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_vote) where individual votes are not recorded.

Comment: If there isn't, then there really should be one.

Comment: @xyldke Including in the UK - and the page linked in the question is only for divisions - i.e. non-voice votes. The vast majority of votes in the UK parliament are voice votes.

Comment: @xyldke, thanks for pointing out. Guess we should live without that data then...